# Adjust date of Carbon object using string

Tags: php, date

I have a Carbon object that returns the string `2021-01-14 09:00:00`, all good.

Now I want to adjust *only* the date using a string of the new date, like `2021-01-21` for example.

I know Carbon has a function called `Carbon::setDate`, but that function requires the format `($year, $month, $day)`. I just have the new date as a **string**, and I don't like having to extract the year, month & day of it each time.

So is there a better way to adjust the date, using a string of the new date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setDateFrom()` to copy the date from one instance to another, something like...

```
$carbon = new Carbon('2021-01-14 09:00:00');
$carbon1 = new Carbon('2021-01-21');

$carbon->setDateFrom($carbon1);

echo $carbon;
```

gives...

```
2021-01-21 09:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the creating format with `createFromFormat()` function of the Carbon.

So you can create with string in date-time or Y-m-d H format or how ever you want.

```
echo Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H', '2021-01-14 09')->toDateTimeString(); //You will get 2021-01-14 09:00:00
```

Comment: Was thinking the same, but I think it should take the position 1 of the explode and concat it with the new date?

Comment: They want to be able to adjust the date and not extract it.

Comment: @NigelRen I don't think so, they just want to date as a string.

Comment: *Now I want to adjust only the date using a string of the new date, like 2021-01-21 for example.*

Comment: @SantiBarbat they wants date, this will be in 0 index of the exploded array.

Comment: They want to "adjust the date", not the time. So it should extract the time from the original date, and concat it with the new date

Comment: Yes, I just want to adjust the date of the Carbon object. I appriciate your answer but having to use '2021-01-14 09' doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: @Acework check my updated answer above. This will work.